# Using regex with pipe separators in Swift 3 to filter out matches

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string

Having looked at quite a few regex stackoverflow questions thus far, I'm a bit confused as to why my regex isn't filtering out the substrings I'd like to remove. I know for swift, I'll need to escape any other escapes that I have.

First, I have an extension on String like so:

```
extension String {
    func stringByRemovingRegexMatches(pattern: String, replaceWith: String = "") -> String? {
        do {
             let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
            print(regex)
            let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
            return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: replaceWith)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    } 
}
```

Let's say for example the text is:

`+++cta\n[![](http://media.test.com/1.jpg)](http://www.test.com/slideshow)\n\n+++\n\n<span class=\"s1\">Hello</span><span class=\"s2\"> World\n\n[cm_image id=\"13501068\"]<img style=\"width: 100%;\" src=\"http://www.test.com/1.jpg\" alt=\"\" />[/cm_image]\n\n[#c: /c/56be30deff2afb50ef000026]||||||`

I want this to return `Hello World\n` in my Swift project, but it seems to only filter out the `<span>`:

`+++cta\n[![](http://media.test.com/1.jpg)](http://www.test.com/slideshow)\n\n+++\n\nHello World\n\n[cm_image id=\"13501068\"]<img style=\"width: 100%;\" src=\"http://www.test.com/1.jpg\" alt=\"\" />[/cm_image]\n\n[#c: /c/56be30deff2afb50ef000026]||||||`

My regex string in Swift is:

```
"\\+(^)\\+|\\\\n\\[(.*)\\|\\|\\|\\|\\|\\||\\\\n\\[c(.*)\\\\n\\\\n|\\+(.*)\\+\\\\n\\\\n|<[^>]+>"
```

You'll notice above I have a print statement of `regex` which matches what I'm putting into regexr, and the string is:

```
<NSRegularExpression: 0x7ff8d576df00> \+(^)\+|\\n\[(.*)\|\|\|\|\|\||\\n\[c(.*)\\n\\n|\+(.*)\+\\n\\n|<[^>]+> 0x1

\+(^)\+|\\n\[(.*)\|\|\|\|\|\||\\n\[c(.*)\\n\\n|\+(.*)\+\\n\\n|<[^>]+>
```

They're both the exact same.

For further clarification, I have a link to regexr [here](http://regexr.com/3f3a1).

Am I doing something incorrect in Swift? Is it that swift doesn't recognize the `(.*)`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your actual string contains newline chars, not combinatiions of ``\`` + `n` what your regex matches now.

Comment: I thought by escaping the ```\``` I would be able to use that as the startIndex and/or endIndex

Comment: I do not get the rules you followed when building the regex. It is too specific and seems to only match 1 exact string. You might as well use [`rx_pattern = "(?s)^\\+{3}.*?<span\\s+class=\"s1\">|</span><span\\s+class=\"s2\">|\n\\[cm.*"`](https://regex101.com/r/4uB1Kt/1).

Comment: yeah sorry about that, I'm looking into figuring out a more generic way of doing it. It's because our editors have a specific way of writing markdown in our cms so I'm filtering all of those out because I'm doing it natively. However, @WiktorStribiżew you just gave me another idea. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: oh ok i'll try that one out too!

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for your help, I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

So making sure that I have `((.|\n)*)` in between my startIndex and endIndex solved this problem because I want all characters or returns between my bounds.

Comment: Do not do that, it is a very bad idea. Use `(?s)` modifier to make `.` match line breaks.